# Showing matplotlib and seaborn graphs in Python Dash doesn't work. How can we make it work?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, seaborn, plotly-dash

I was trying to show output of heatmap and pitch map for soccer players using seaborn and matplotlib. In offline, I could be able to render them but it does not seem to work in Python Dash. Problem could be that maybe Python Dash cannot render matplotlib or seaborn.. How can we show heatmap pitch graph in Dash??

I tried different things such as mpl_to_plotly(fig) but still didn't work. I got an error messaging saying cannot get window extent w/o renderer mpl_to_plotly..

Here is the code:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import json
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import urllib.request


with urllib.request.urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/statsbomb/open-data/master/data/events/7567.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)
    event = json_normalize(data, sep = "_")

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']    

available_indicators = event['player_name'].unique()

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1('WC 2018 - Pitch Pass Heatmap'),


    html.Div(''' South Korea vs Germany '''),

    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='my-dropdown',
        options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in available_indicators],
        value='Toni Kroos'
    ),
   # dcc.Store(
   #     id='example-graph'
   # )
    html.Div(id='example-graph')
])    



@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output(component_id='example-graph', component_property='children'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input(component_id='my-dropdown', component_property='value')]
)



# Let combine all 3: pitch, annotation and heatmap -- draw all of them on the pitch at the same time
def combine_heat_pitch_map(selected_dropdown_value, type_name = "Pass", data = event):
    # let's filter data
    type_data = data[(data['type_name'] == type_name) & (data['player_name']==selected_dropdown_value)]
    movement_data = data[data['player_name']==selected_dropdown_value]

    # pitch
    fig=plt.figure() #set up the figures
    fig.set_size_inches(7, 5)
    ax=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
    # draw_pitch(ax) #overlay our different objects on the pitch




    # focus on only half of the pitch
    #Pitch Outline & Centre Line
    Pitch = plt.Rectangle([0,0], width = 120, height = 80, fill = False)
    #Left, Right Penalty Area and midline
    LeftPenalty = plt.Rectangle([0,22.3], width = 14.6, height = 35.3, fill = False)
    RightPenalty = plt.Rectangle([105.4,22.3], width = 14.6, height = 35.3, fill = False)
    midline = mpl.patches.ConnectionPatch([60,0], [60,80], "data", "data")

    #Left, Right 6-yard Box
    LeftSixYard = plt.Rectangle([0,32], width = 4.9, height = 16, fill = False)
    RightSixYard = plt.Rectangle([115.1,32], width = 4.9, height = 16, fill = False)


    #Prepare Circles
    centreCircle = plt.Circle((60,40),8.1,color="black", fill = False)
    centreSpot = plt.Circle((60,40),0.71,color="black")
    #Penalty spots and Arcs around penalty boxes
    leftPenSpot = plt.Circle((9.7,40),0.71,color="black")
    rightPenSpot = plt.Circle((110.3,40),0.71,color="black")
    leftArc = mpl.patches.Arc((9.7,40),height=16.2,width=16.2,angle=0,theta1=310,theta2=50,color="black")
    rightArc = mpl.patches.Arc((110.3,40),height=16.2,width=16.2,angle=0,theta1=130,theta2=230,color="black")

    element = [Pitch, LeftPenalty, RightPenalty, midline, LeftSixYard, RightSixYard, centreCircle, 
               centreSpot, rightPenSpot, leftPenSpot, leftArc, rightArc]
    for i in element:
        ax.add_patch(i)




    plt.axis('off')


    # annotation of type_name 
    for i in range(len(type_data)):
        # annotate draw an arrow from a current position to pass_end_location
        color = "blue" if type_data.iloc[i]['period'] == 1 else "red"  # If passes are from halftime, color blue, otherwise red
       # label = "1st half" if type_data.iloc[i]['period'] == 1 else "2nd half"
        ax.annotate("", xy = (type_data.iloc[i]['pass_end_location'][0], type_data.iloc[i]['pass_end_location'][1]), xycoords = 'data',
                   xytext = (type_data.iloc[i]['location'][0], type_data.iloc[i]['location'][1]), textcoords = 'data',
                   arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->",connectionstyle="arc3", color = color,),)
        #ax.legend()

    # heatmap of entire movement
    x_coord = [i[0] for i in movement_data["location"]]
    y_coord = [i[1] for i in movement_data["location"]]

        #shades: give us the heat map we desire
        # n_levels: draw more lines, the larger n, the more blurry it looks
    sns.kdeplot(x_coord, y_coord, shade = "True", color = "green", n_levels = 30)

    # Draw all of them on the pitch
    plt.ylim(-2, 82)
    plt.xlim(-2, 122)
   # plt.legend(loc='upper right')
    #figure = plt.show()
    plt.show()
    #return figure


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

Comment: Hey there! Could you include the traceback of the error in your question? This shall help other people understand what is happening.

Comment: `plt.show()` does not return a figure object. You should use a `dcc.Graph()` component in your layout and the `Output` of your callback function should be the `figure` attribute of the `dcc.Graph()` component in your layout

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using `Plotly` in place of `matplotlib` and `seaborn` here, considering that Dash is built on top of `Plotly`. I've created a similar sample to what you have in your original post here, using [Shapes](https://www.plot.ly/python/shapes/) and [Annotations](https://plot.ly/python/text-and-annotations/):

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

import json, random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import urllib.request

with urllib.request.urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/statsbomb/open-data/master/data/events/7567.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)
    event = json_normalize(data, sep = "_")

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']    

available_indicators = event['player_name'].unique()

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div([

    html.H1('WC 2018 - Pitch Pass Heatmap'),

    html.H3(''' South Korea vs Germany '''),

    html.Div(style={'width': '20%'}, children=[
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id='my-dropdown',
            options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in available_indicators],
            value='Toni Kroos'
        )
    ]),

    html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(id='example-graph')
    ]),

])    


@app.callback(
    Output('example-graph', 'figure'),
    [Input('my-dropdown', 'value')])
def combine_heat_pitch_map(value, type_name="Pass"):

    type_data = event[(event['type_name']==type_name) & (event['player_name']==value)]
    movement_data = event[event['player_name']==value]

    annotations = [
        {'x': random.randint(5, 115), 'y': random.randint(5, 75), 'xref': 'x', 'yref': 'y', 'text': ''}
    for i in range(len(type_data))]

    fig = {

        'data': [],

        'layout': {

            'height': 500,
            'width': 700,

            'xaxis': {
                'range': [-2, 122],
                'showticklabels': False,
                'showgrid': False,
                'zeroline': False,
            },

            'yaxis': {
                'range': [-2, 82],
                'showticklabels': False,
                'showgrid': False,
                'zeroline': False,
            },

            'shapes': [
                #Pitch
                {'type': 'rect', 'x0': 0, 'y0': 0, 'x1': 120, 'y1': 80},
                #Left Penalty
                {'type': 'rect', 'x0': 0, 'y0': 22.3, 'x1': 0+14.6, 'y1': 22.3+35.3},
                #Right Penalty
                {'type': 'rect', 'x0': 105.4, 'y0': 22.3, 'x1': 105.4+14.6, 'y1': 22.3+35.3},
                #Midline
                {'type': 'line', 'x0': 60, 'y0': 0, 'x1': 60, 'y1': 80},
                #Left Six Yard
                {'type': 'rect', 'x0': 0, 'y0': 32, 'x1': 0+4.9, 'y1': 32+16},
                #Right Six Yard
                {'type': 'rect', 'x0': 115.1, 'y0': 32, 'x1': 115.1+4.9, 'y1': 32+16},
                #Center Circle
                {'type': 'circle', 'xref': 'x', 'yref': 'y', 'x0': 60-8.1, 'y0': 40-8.1, 'x1': 60+8.1, 'y1': 40+8.1},
                #Center Spot
                {'type': 'circle', 'xref': 'x', 'yref': 'y', 'x0': 60-0.71, 'y0': 40-0.71, 'x1': 60+0.71, 'y1': 40+0.71},
                #Left Pen Spot
                {'type': 'circle', 'xref': 'x', 'yref': 'y', 'x0': 110.3-0.71, 'y0': 40-0.71, 'x1': 110.3+0.71, 'y1': 40+0.71},
                #Right Pen Spot
                {'type': 'circle', 'xref': 'x', 'yref': 'y', 'x0': 9.7-0.71, 'y0': 40-0.71, 'x1': 9.7+0.71, 'y1': 40+0.71},
            ],

            'annotations': annotations
        }

    }

    return fig

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

This should provide something that looks similar to the image below:

[image]